# How to configure NetBeans 7.3.1 with Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I want to know *How to configure NetBeans 7.3.1 with Tomcat 8.0* without getting the **specified server location (catalina home) folder is not valid** error?

I have searched over internet but found no solution.

Comment: Tomcat 8 still in alpha status.

Comment: Should I use Tomcat 7

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans currently supports Tomcat 7.0.34 per the [download page](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) and [installation notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/install.html).

The Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 6 Update 26 (or later) or JDK 7 Update 10 (or later) is required to install the NetBeans IDE.